# What are the rules for selecting HTML text nodes in CSS?

Tags: html, css, text

Just playing around with HTML/CSS and wondered how the browser handles chunks of text that are not enclosed in a tag. When I run the below code, all three text chunks (in `<head>`, between `<head>` and `<body>`, and in `<body>`) picked up the red "body" styling.

Why would text strings outside `<body>` pick up the "body" rule?

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test web page</title>
   head text outside a tag
  </head>
  Text node between head and body
  <body>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>
      Some paragraph text
    </p>
    some body text outside a tag
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  color:red;
}

h1, p {
  color:lightblue;
}

head {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Because your HTML is invalid and the browser just tries to make sense of it. Every normal text should be in the `body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not really CSS related; the CSS only makes the problem *visible*.

When the browser parses the HTML, it follows a number of rules.

1. The head cannot contain plain text; the body can
2. Some start and end tags are optional
3. If there's an error; try to work around it

So if the parser encounters some plain text in the head, it knows that the text doesn't belong there. It first inserts an invisible `</head>` end tag followed by an invisible `<body>` start tag and then happily continues parsing.
And this is not even the error handling at work, this is just how normal parsing rules work!

The error handling routines only come into action when the parser then encounters a `</head>` tag, which isn't allowed in the body. It then ignores this tag and continues. Same with the `<body>` tag later, which is also not allowed in the body.
So, that's what it does, and why you get those results.